# Testing convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{3n^{4}+4}{3n^{5}+3}$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{3n^{4}+4}{3n^{5}+3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

trying to determine if the series is absolutely convergent/ conditionally convergent or divergent. 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{3n^{4}+4}{3n^{5}+3}$$

dividing by $$n^{5}$$ the limit approaches 0 as n -> infinity. I believe it is absolutely convergent by the ratio test. 

Also, does the answer change if it becomes an alternating series ie. 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{3n^{4}+4}{3n^{5}+3}$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{3n^4+4}{3n^5+3}\ge\frac1n$ when $4n\gt3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum \frac{3n^4+4}{3n^5+3} \sim \sum \frac{3n^4}{3n^5}=\sum \frac{1}{n}$$

Hence it doesn't converge absolutely.

Apply the Alternating series test to show that $\sum (-1)^n \frac{3n^4+4}{3n^5+3}$ converges.

Hence, the series is conditionally convergent.

Comment: going through the alternating series test 
i) series needs to decrease, which it does.
ii) bn -> 0 as n->0
meeting both these conditions the alternating series the series converges ?

Comment: Yes. Also note that $b_n >0$, which is also required.

Comment: how would i check for absolute/conditional convergence ?

Comment: I have edited the answer for more clarity.

Comment: thanks so much for the help :)